# ¿Como Actualizo registros de la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código lo que busco es actulizar los datos de los registros pero no me funciona.

**modificandoFormato.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Creando...</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Actualizando Datos</h1>
        <form action="modificandoEstadoAmbu.php" method="post">
            <br><label>Placa: </label>
            <input type="text" name="placa" placeholder="placa" class="input-48" style="margin-left: 2%"></br>

            <br><label>Estado: </label>
            <input type="text" name="estado" placeholder="Disponibilidad" class="input-48"></br>

            <br><label>Tipo De Ambulancia:</label>
            <input type="text" name="tipo_Ambulancia" placeholder="Tipo De Ambulancia" class="input-48"></br>

            <br><input type="button" value="Volver!" onclick="location='http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Administracion/editarCliente.php'" />

            <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" class="btn-enviar"></br>

    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**modificandoEstadoAmbu.php**

```
<?php
        $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");


        $placa = $_POST["placa"];
        $estado = $_POST["estado"];
        $tipo_Ambulancia = $_POST["tipo_Ambulancia"];

        mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE ambulancia SET placa = '".$placa."', estado = '".$estado."', tipo_Ambulancia = '".$tipo_Ambulancia."' WHERE placa ='".$placa."'") or die("Error al actualizar");

?>
```

Comment: ¿Que tipo de datos son cada campo?

Comment: son varchar todos

Comment: Te sale algún error al enviar el formulario?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: placa 

Notice: Undefined index: estado  

Notice: Undefined index: tipo_Ambulancia

Comment: Intenta mostrando los valores del post o viéndolos en las herramientas del navegador

Comment: como hago eso ?

Comment: `mysqli_query(...) or die($_POST)`

Comment: tambien cierra la etiqeta form

Comment: en donde ubico ese codigo

Comment: A cual código te refieres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
    <?php
    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", 
    "root","admin123","database");

    $placa = $_POST["placa"];
    $estado = $_POST["estado"];
    $tipo_Ambulancia = $_POST["tipo_Ambulancia"];

    mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE ambulancia SET placa = '$placa', 
    estado = '$estado', tipo_Ambulancia = '$tipo_Ambulancia' WHERE placa 
    ='$placa'") or die("Error al actualizar");?>
```

creeria que tu problema es querer concatenar los campos, algo que te puede servir para depurar codigo es usar:

```
        var_dump($estado.'-'.$placa.'-'.$tipo_Ambulancia);exit();
```

antes de hacer el update solo para ver que valor llevan las variables. ya luego lo eliminas o lo comentas y debe fucnionar.

Comment: voy a mirarlos aver

Comment: Men muchas gracias si me sirvio

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido, ya sabes como votar ;)